# Is ISO C++ code directly compilable in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, c++, c++-cli, portability

I want to write some library code to be shared across products and across platforms, including OS X and .Net.

My current research suggests that writing this core library code in C++ is a good approach. Obviously I could also use Java but it's not my strong suit - I'd rather stick with ObjC / C++ / C# where I can.

I believe that C++/CLI is the current choice for C++ in .Net so my question is; is C++/CLI a strict superset of 'vanilla' ISO C++? In other words if I write C++ code that compiles under `gcc`, for example, can I compile that without change (or with a few conditional compiles) under C++/CLI?

Obviously I will have to write wrappers around system functions, I/O etc. - that's fine - but I want the core algorithmic code to be as portable as possible.

Comment: BTW, I'm basing this architecture on the advice in this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252514/create-a-cross-platform-windows-mac-os-x-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, but not necessarily. For example, the STL/CLR is hideously slow in comparison to the BCL, and some things like nullptr refer to the managed nullptr, not the native nullptr. Even if your app compiled cleanly for .NET, that doesn't make it the right thing to do.

It would be much more reasonable to compile the native side to a DLL and then P/Invoke from C# if you must offer a managed interface. This will be much more reliable.

Comment: STL/CLR isn't ISO C++ code.  ISO C++ code compiles with the C++/CLI compiler in almost all cases, and C++/CLI wrappers are an order of magnitude easier to write and maintain than P/Invoke declarations, and give better performance to boot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Performance is a very good point of course; I might try both Native C++ via PInvoke and C++/CLI to compare speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use C# then you could rely on Mono to provide cross-platform capabilities.  An alternative might be to provide C# and a native, portable C++ version.

If you really need a managed code version outside Windows I would use Java.  Learning Java is a lot more useful than C++/CLI, and porting to Java from C# is not likely to be rocket science.

I would avoid C++/CLI unless you absolutely **must** do it for some rich/important customer.

Prioritization of implementation(s) should depend on the expected market requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately significant chunks of the BCL are architected far worse than the underlying Win32 API.  And C++/CLI is by far the best option for bringing native APIs to .NET.  Java is absolutely horrible for interacting with native APIs, JNI is nowhere near as easy to use as P/Invoke, let alone C++ interop.

Comment: The problem is I want to use WPF in Windows and Cocoa in OS X. Not Swing etc. so Java isn't really an option for me I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

**NO IT WILL NOT**

- According to the MSDN documentation it will. But it's a nasty lie. I have fallen into this trap. When already thousands LOC's were written, it turned out that CLI has problems with boost::thread. The latter just doesn't work. So I assume that there may be other things too. So just don't go there, that's my good advice.
- Even without CLI you cannot assume that everything that compiles with gcc will compile with MSVC, because the latter has many ISO compliance issues. Worse, both can compile but run differently. Microsoft sucks so hard... but their IDE is just superb :)

Comment: boost::thread isn't "vanilla ISO C++" to begin with. It supports certain implementations, but if C++/CLI isn't one of them it doesn't *necessarily* prove anything.

Comment: Both compilers have compliance issues.